# Print lines after a pattern until second occurrence of a different pattern

Tags: bash, sed

So I know how to print lines from one pattern to another pattern:

```
sed -ne '/pattern_1/,/pattern_2/ p'
```

Which works for input that looks like this:

```
random_line_1
pattern_1
random_line_2
random_line_3
random_line_4
random_line_5
pattern_2
random_line_6
```

So that lines from `pattern_1` to `pattern_2` get printed.

But how can I print lines until the **second** occurrence of the second pattern:

```
random_line_1
pattern_1
pattern_2
random_line_3
random_line_4
random_line_5
pattern_2
random_line_6
```

I want to print the lines from `pattern_1` to the **second** `pattern_2` so that I get this as output:

```
pattern_1
pattern_2
random_line_3
random_line_4
random_line_5
pattern_2
```

More specifically, I am trying to capture text, starting at a header, that is surrounded by empty lines, that may or may not have text before the header and after the **second** empty line (where `pattern_1` is the header and `pattern_2` is the empty line):

```
Header:
<empty line>
     Some_text
     Some_more_text
     Even_more_text
     When_will_it_stop
<empty line>
```

Preferably, a `sed` answer would work best since I know a little bit about how it works, but I would be open to `awk` submissions, as long as every piece of the command is explained.

Comment: Honestly I didn't understand your second example of questions(empty lines one), I have added code as per 1st example now, if it needs to be added more conditions, kindly make it little clear in the post of second example.

Comment: It's a specific example of the question I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler sed example for your specific case:

`sed -ne '/pattern_1/,/pattern_2/{/pattern_1/N;p}'`

This just says that within the range, suck the line after the header `pattern_1` into the pattern space and print it.  This means that if the line after `pattern_1` is `pattern_2`, that occurence of `pattern_2` will not count for the range.

In other words:
`sed -ne '/Header/,/^$/{/Header/N;p}'`

Comment: Takes the cake for satisfying the `sed` requirement. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not at a machine on which to test, but you should be able to do something very simple to understand just with `grep` and its *"context"* switches (`-A`, `-B` and `-C`).

So to delete all lines before `pattern1`, simply find `pattern1` and all lines after (`-A`):

```
grep -A 9999 "pattern1" YourFile
```

Then, in the result, search for the second occurrence (`-m2`) of `pattern2` and everything before (`-B`):

```
grep -A 9999 "pattern1" YourFile | grep -B 9999 -m2 "pattern2"
```

Comment: Wow, didn't think it was something I could do with `grep`.

Comment: So for my specific example and based on your answer, I came up with this: `grep -A 9999 Header: | grep -B 9999 -m2 "^ *$"`. I tried the regex syntax for an empty line and, hey, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much! I needed the top two <VirtualHost>...</VirtualHost> sections out of an Apache config file and `grep -FB 9999 -m2 "</VirtualHost>"` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/pattern_1/{a=1}
a<3 && a;
/pattern_2/{a++}
' Input_file
```

Adding code with explanation as follows too.

```
awk '/pattern_1/{a=1} ##Searching for string /pattern_1/ in a line, if it is present in a line then making variable a value as 1.
a<3 && a; ##Now checking if variable a value is less than 3 and it is NOT NULL, so if both conditions are TRUE then didnot define any action, so by default print action will happen on current line of the Input_file.
/pattern_2/{a++} ##Searching string pattern_2 in a line and incrementing the value of variable a with 1 each time it sees this string in a line.
' Input_file ##mentioning Input_file name over here.
```

Comment: Almost works, but I get text before the first pattern.

Comment: Could you please post sample data which you are using, because it works for me for the provided sample Input_file.

Comment: If I set `pattern_1` to `Header2:` and `pattern_2` to `^ *$`, I get text before `Header2:`. This is the command I am running: `awk '/Header2:/{a=1}a<3 && a;/^ *$/{a++}' temp` where `temp` is the name of the file with the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/pattern_1/{:a;N;s/pattern_2/&/2p;Ta}' file
```

From the address containing `pattern_1` gather up the following lines in the pattern space until the second substitution of the `pattern_2` has been successfully printed.

For your particular example, use:

```
sed -n '/Header:/{:a;N;s/\n$/&/mp2;Ta}' file
```

N.B. the `m` flag allows for matching on multiple lines within the pattern space. The `T` command is the opposite of the `t` command, which jumps to location `:x` (where `x` is user defined) when the previous substitution is successful.

Comment: What does `N` do? That's the same as `n;p` or `p;n`, right?

Comment: I also can't seem to get the empty line syntax to work. I think because there is a carriage return in the empty line as well, since the text originated on Windows. I tried `^ *$` in place of `pattern_2` but that didn't work.

Comment: @wheeler `N` appends a newline and a new line to the pattern space. A return can be represented by `\r` so an empty line might be represented by `\n\r*\s*$`.